# Callback Method not firing from library

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a method which is supposed to be called once a BLE device is connected. but for some reason this is not happening.
There are multiple view controllers which are all doing there job first, but the final one which should update a label is not being called, this is called realDataCallBackWithData.

here is the code in **viewController.m** that is not being called:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CRPC_300SDK.h"
#import "CRBlueToothManager.h"
#import "CRHeartLiveView.h"
#import "DataObject.h"
#import "IntervalGraph.h"
#import <VTO2Lib/VTO2Lib.h>
#import "VTBLEUtils.h"
#import "VTConnectViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<CRPC_300SDKDelegate,CRBlueToothManagerDelegate,VTO2CommunicateDelegate>
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [VTO2Communicate sharedInstance].delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark VTO2Parser Update

//This is the method which when called should activate the realDataCallBackWithData method below.

- (void)readRealtimeData{
    if (self.deviceCom.sensorConnected == NO){
        NSLog(@"readRealtimeData NOT activated, sensor state %d", self.deviceCom.sensorConnected);
    }else if (self.deviceCom.sensorConnected == YES){
        
    NSLog (@"readRealtimeData activated");
    [[VTO2Communicate sharedInstance] beginGetRealData];
    }
}

// This is the method not being called:

-(void)realDataCallBackWithData:(NSData *)realData
{
    if (realData == nil){
        NSLog(@"error");
        return;
    }
    VTRealObject *rObj = [VTO2Parser parseO2RealObjectWithData:realData];
    u_char hr = rObj.hr;
    _spo2Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",hr];
    NSLog(@"O2Ring HR = %hhu", hr);
    
    
}
```

for reference, here is the **VTO2Communicate.h**:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>
#import "VTO2Def.h"

@class VTFileToRead;
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@protocol VTO2CommunicateDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

- (void)serviceDeployed:(BOOL)completed;

/// @brief Common command send to peripheral,   callback
/// @param cmdType command for VTCmdTypeSyncParam/VTCmdTypeSetFactory
/// @param result view the enum VTProCommonResult
- (void)commonResponse:(VTCmdType)cmdType andResult:(VTCommonResult)result;

/// @brief Send the current progress of reading
/// @param progress progress value
- (void)postCurrentReadProgress:(double)progress;

/// @brief Read file complete
/// @param fileData view model --- VTFileToRead
- (void)readCompleteWithData:(VTFileToRead *)fileData;

/// @brief get information complete . if infoData == nil , an error occurred
/// @param infoData information data nullable
- (void)getInfoWithResultData:(NSData * _Nullable)infoData;

/// @brief use  `parseO2RealObjectWithData` to parse realData.  if realData == nil , an error occurred.
/// @param realData  real data
- (void)realDataCallBackWithData:(NSData * _Nullable)realData;

/// @brief use `` to parse realPPG.  if realPPG == nil , an error occurred.
/// @param realPPG real PPG data
- (void)realPPGCallBackWithData:(NSData * _Nullable)realPPG;

/// @brief read current peripheral's rssi
/// @param RSSI rssi
- (void)updatePeripheralRSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI;

@end

@interface VTO2Communicate : NSObject

/// @brief This peripheral is currently connected. Need to be set after connection
@property (nonatomic, strong) CBPeripheral *peripheral;

/// @brief current file been read or written
@property (nonatomic, strong) VTFileToRead *curReadFile;

/// @brief time out       ms
@property (nonatomic, assign) u_int timeout;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<VTO2CommunicateDelegate> _Nullable delegate;

+ (VTO2Communicate *)sharedInstance;

- (void)readRSSI;

/// @brief Get information of peripheral. callback `getInfoWithResultData:`
- (void)beginGetInfo;

/// @brief Get real-time data. callback `realDataCallBackWithData:`
- (void)beginGetRealData;


/// @brief Restore factory. callback `commonResponse: andResult:`
- (void)beginFactory;

/// @brief get PPG data.
- (void)beginGetRealPPG;

/// @brief set params .  all type view struct  `VTParamType`  .  callback `commonResponse: andResult:`
/// @param paramType param type
/// @param paramValue param content/value
- (void)beginToParamType:(VTParamType)paramType content:(NSString *)paramValue;
 
/// @brief Download file from peripheral.   callback `readCompleteWithData:`  & `postCurrentReadProgress:`
/// @param fileName file's name
- (void)beginReadFileWithFileName:(NSString *)fileName;

@end


/// @brief this is a class to describe the completeed current loading or writing file
@interface VTFileToRead : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *fileName;

@property (nonatomic, assign) u_int fileSize;

@property (nonatomic, assign) u_int totalPkgNum;

@property (nonatomic, assign) u_int curPkgNum;

@property (nonatomic, assign) u_int lastPkgSize;

/// @brief download completed response data .
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *fileData;

/// @brief read file result
@property (nonatomic, assign) VTFileLoadResult enLoadResult;



@end


NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

and the **VTO2Parser.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "VTO2Info.h"
#import "VTO2Object.h"
#import "VTO2WaveObject.h"
#import "VTRealObject.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface VTO2Parser : NSObject

/// @brief parse O2 information
/// @param infoData infoData from peripheral
+ (VTO2Info *)parseO2InfoWithData:(NSData * _Nonnull)infoData;

/// @brief parse O2 object
/// @param fileData fileData from peripheral
+ (VTO2Object *)parseO2ObjectWithData:(NSData * _Nonnull)fileData;

/// @brief parse O2 Wave array .
/// @param waveData waveData from  VTO2Object
+ (NSArray <VTO2WaveObject *>*)parseO2WaveObjectArrayWithWaveData:(NSData * _Nonnull)waveData;

/// @brief parse O2 Real-time data
/// @param realData realData from peripheral
+ (VTRealObject *)parseO2RealObjectWithData:(NSData *)realData;

/// @brief parse O2 Real PPG data
/// @param realPPG real PPG data from peripheral
+ (NSArray <VTRealPPG *>*)parseO2RealPPGWithData:(NSData *)realPPG;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Everything else is being called and i have confirmed this in the logs, it is only the method in the viewController.m which is not firing, can someone tell me where i have gone wrong?

Comment: You can have only one delegate at a time. Also, where did you call the method parse that might trigger the delegate method?

Comment: @Larme thanks for helping, i didnt think i was calling more than one delegate at the point when the callback was called. The method which triggers the parse is in the VTConnectViewController.m and is the readRealTimeData method. This in turns begins calling data from the VTO2Parser method which contains the callback realDataCallbackWithData.

Comment: @Larme i edited the code above to bring all of the relevant code into the one view controller. This is to ensure no other delegates would be called as you suggested this could be an issue. The problem is still occurring.

Comment: You are complaining that `readRealtimeData` is never called. But I do not see any code that would ever call it. Why do you think it should be called?

Comment: Hi @Matt that method is being called, it is not the problem, i am not complaining that it is not being called. The method which is not being called is realDataCallbackWithData, that is a callback method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the solution to the problem was to re-declare the delegate after the peripheral was connected, i did this by adding the following line of code into the readRealTimeData method:

```
[VTO2Communicate sharedInstance].delegate = self;
```

here is how the now working method looks:

```
- (void)readRealtimeData{
    if (self.deviceCom.sensorConnected == NO){
        NSLog(@"readRealtimeData NOT activated, sensor state %d", self.deviceCom.sensorConnected);
    }else if (self.deviceCom.sensorConnected == YES){
        
    NSLog (@"readRealtimeData activated");
    [VTO2Communicate sharedInstance].delegate = self;
    [[VTO2Communicate sharedInstance] beginGetRealData];
    }
}
```

This ensured that the delegate was reset before the callback was fired.